# AS3 - Saving variable attached to each user in kongregate

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm new in game making and API things. I'm trying to make a game which can save player's gold and item.
I was trying to do that using SharedObject. But, as I know, using SharedObject makes the data saved locally in the computer. What's the best way to save the variable in server-side? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MY best guess: write files on the server using PHP. Are you familiar with how to do that?

Comment: so we have to use our domain, and make php file. and then, send and retrieve data from as3. am i correct?

Comment: That's it. PHP has to running on your server, of course. There's plenty of online documentaion on how to use Flash/AS3 to send requests to PHP.